Are there effective any-angle pathfinding algorithms for infinite weighted grids?
I am developing a game that involves pathfinding on terrain where different surfaces have different movement costs (e.g., snow, mud, etc.). I need an any-angle pathfinding algorithm that works efficiently on an infinite weighted grid with these varying terrain costs. The goal is to find the shortest path that accounts for the weights of each type of terrain.
I've tried implementing a cost function for Theta* that considers the weight of each node under the line between each waypoint into account, but that didn't work. It was very inefficient and didn't find an optimal path. It often searched in the opposite direction.
function cost(node1, node2)
    initialize totalCost to 0

    points = supercover(node1, node2)

    for each point in points except the last one do
        node = getNode(point.x, point.y)
        nextPoint = next point in points
        nextNode = getNode(nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y)
        
        if nextNode is not found then
            exit loop
        end

        distance = euclidean_distance(node, nextNode)

        if nextNode.material exists in costs then
            multiplier = costs[nextNode.material]
        else
            multiplier = 1
        end

        totalCost = totalCost + (distance * multiplier)
    end

    return totalCost
end function


@ravenspoint By any-angled I mean the path can travel in any direction like described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any-angle_path_planning
Does Dijkstra support any-angled paths?

I am not sure that I fully understand this "any-angled" thing.  Does it mean that the path can jump from any grid point to any other, without bothering to go through any in-between points?  Is there a limit to how far these jumps can go?  Why not jump from source to destination in one leap?

@ravenspoint Yes. The path can jump from any grid point to any other if there is a line of sight between them.

And how is the existence of a "line of sight" specified?  You do not mention anything of the sort in your question.

Assuming that you have specified every pair of vertices that are reachable from each other with one costed hop then the most 'efficient' path finding algorithm is Dijkstra.

@ravenspoint The line of sight is determined by checking for obstacles between two points. If there's a clear path with no obstacles, then they have a line of sight. There isn't a limit to how far these jumps can go, as long as the line of sight condition is met. I get that Dijkstra is efficient, but as far as I know, I don't think Djikstra supports any-angle paths directly.

So now you have introduced "obstacles", another thing you do not mention in your question.  If your input specifies these obstacles, then you can calculate every pair of vertices that are reachable from each other with one costed hop and apply Dijsktra to the resulting graph.

Are there any other surprises you are waiting to spring on us?

@ravenspoint "Any angle pathfinding" is a commonly-used, well-defined term.  OP already linked the wikipedia article for it.

How is your terrain defined?  I ask, because in many cases the best path will trace closely around patches of expensive terrain, and if your terrain is defined on a grid, then defeat the "any angle" effect that you're trying to achieve.  Your best bet may be to use a grid-based path finder to find the entry and exit in each patch of uniform terrain, and then use an any-angle method within each uniform patch.
